# How to store files in Azure's filesystem

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am writing a simple API that's hosted on Azure, and I need a place to store a config file that can be changed in the code. I want to place this in the webroot.

Before you say this is a terrible practice, I know. This API is very small(the free version of Azure is actually more than enough for me), and the file is less than 1MB in size. I don't want to buy blob storage or other things that are designed to be for large projects. I don't really care about scalability, I just want the data to persist.

The question is where and how can I store this file. Can I use the path "D:/home/site/" or something similar? What do I need to do to make this work? And if this is impossible, are there other options for me that hopefully isn't overkill?

Comment: "a simple API that's hosted on Azure": App Service? API App? VM? Functions? Cloud Service?

Comment: It's hosted as App Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is where and how can I store this file. Can I use the path "D:/home/site/" or something similar? What do I need to do to make this work?

It seems that you are hosting your API application on Azure app service and you'd like to find a place that can be used to persist a config file. As you mentioned, you can store your file in `d:\home`, and the file would be persistent and shared between all instances of your site. This article can help you understand [the Azure App Service file system](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system), please read it.

You can upload this config file when you deploy your API application or upload it via [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console).